# Connect Raspberry Pi GPIO to 5V with only 1 resistor

Tags: gpio

Hi everyone,

I've have always connected 5V inputs to my Raspberry Pi through a voltage divider (2 resistors). But I'm now wondering why ? What is the precise reason ?

Is a circuit like "5V-->Resistor-->GPIO" safe ? If not, why ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are talking about 5v logic circuits. You could specify the value of the resistors.

The Pi GPIO would be damaged by connection to anything higher than 3.3v. A divider is one way of reducing voltage, but level shifter or clamp are more conventional (and better) solutions. For non-demanding (slow speed) applications this is OK.

PS If you were thinking of just connecting via a series resistor - DON"T. This may limit the current after it has damaged the input.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I just wonder WHY it's not possible to connect via series resistor ? What's the electrical reason ? Why isn't it working ?

Thank you again.

Comment: A resistor only drops the voltage when current is flowing. That current flow is what causes the damage. Putting a voltage above the 3.3v supply upsets the internal bias within the chip with unpredictable results.